# Route 53 and S3 not working properly (transfered domain)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I have a website transferred from Gandi to AWS.
I create a bucket named [www.develinside.com](http://www.develinside.com) setup as website:

http://www.develinside.com.s3-website.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/

When I call http://www.develinside.com/ I have a *DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN*.
The NS is the default one and I wait some days.

I also used dig as explained [here](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/route-53-reachable-resource-record-sets). Everything seems to be ok but it is not working.

Here is my Route 53 setup *I checked 3 times the S3 bucket*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain you've added does not appear to have any NS records when performing a DIG lookup, in fact it returns `SERVFAIL` which indicates an error in querying the name server.

The whois records indicates that it has its configured nameservers registered to the following (which I presume have no records):

- Name Server: A.DNS.GANDI.NET
- Name Server: B.DNS.GANDI.NET
- Name Server: C.DNS.GANDI.NET

In the AWS Console, do the following to update this.

- Access the Route 53 console.
- Select Registered domains in the menu.
- Click on your domain name
- Click `Add or edit name servers`
- Enter the Name Server values

Until this is done, none of your records will resolve. More information is available [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/domain-name-servers-glue-records.html#domain-name-servers-glue-records-adding-changing).

Comment: My domain have been transfered from gandi to aws. My NS records have been setup automatically by amazon as you can see in the picture. Why did it appear  to be on gandi ?

Comment: Hmm, right within the console find the registered domain (not the public hosted zone). It should have a value for `Nameservers`. Check the values match your public hosted zones pictures, I presume this will have the gandi values in it. Edit them to replace with Route 53 Name Servers.

Comment: Hello, I made the changes as you said on more than two days ago and when I check on whois my changes seems not have been taken in account. I ping the aws NS and have a response. How much time can it take ?

Comment: I can see DNS records are now there, it depends on the values that Gandi would have set. I've seen TTLs of upto 7 days but I'd not expect as long as that. Are you able to connect to the site from your browser?

Comment: Nope, I'm wrong I change it on Wednesday, so maybe I have to wait until Monday.

Comment: Works for me (loads the string "Hello World") when loading via HTTP :)

Comment: It works on safari not on chrome. I will check why. Thank you very much for your help. Have a nice day.

Comment: Chrome caches DNS too:https://www.howtogeek.com/197804/how-to-clear-the-google-chrome-dns-cache-on-windows/. Have a great day :)